# Creating a query that can be numerically evaluated in Access

Tags: ms-access, wildcard

I'm trying to get some of the data provided to me clean enough to be evaluated. I've been provided with testing data that has special characters in it. For example, a large proportion has the value `<0.5**` or `<0.5*` indicating that the level of contaminant is below 0.5 PPM. However, this doesn't help much when I'm trying to evaluate that column.

I'm trying to figure out if the best way is to create a query and use that, or to create a new field and use an update query to remove the special characters. However, I can't figure out how to create a query from these values that can be evaluated numerically, and whenever I try and run an update query with `Replace(Replace([SampleResult],"*",""),"<","")` it doesn't output anything.

Comment: In the immediate window `?Replace(Replace("<5**","*",""),"<","")` returns `5` for me. I think your replace is good. How are you using it?

Comment: Also, take a look at the `val()` function. You could do something like `val(Replace("<5**","<",""))` and it would return `5`. It stops processing when it hits a non-number.